# Check database for similar value , MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table server like this;

```
Model | Brand
-------------------
M4000 | Dell
S4000 | Hp
S3500 | Hp
S6500 | Sun
```

I want to display different data from the 'Brand' field which means I don't want the second 'Hp' data to display again. How do I do that?

Comment: DISTINCT in MySQL may help here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Brand FROM tableName
```

Comment: No problem, Mister Abdullah. Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if it answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize DISTINCT:

```
select distinct (brand) from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Using distinct will cause only once instance of Brand to display, like this. So, use

```
select distinct Brand from your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Brand FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

For example purposes let's assume your table name is mod_brand, then this SQL statement will group together by brand:

```
select m.*
from   mod_brand m
group  by Brand;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'GROUP BY' keyword, but in this case you get just one data for each Brand (the first 'Model' data).

Else you can use 'DISTINCT' and you get many same 'Brand' values.

PS: I'm French sorry for my english....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select distinct brand from tablename
```

Otherwise, try this:

```
select brand,group_concat(model) from table group by brand
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

SELECT Model FROM tableName GROUP BY Brand